# Syntax for css element selector?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

[![html and css][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5y3p.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5y3p.png][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5y3p.png%5D%5B1%5D)
what is the proper syntax to make this css element selector work? I cannot seem to change the background color of my page

Comment: Share body content as well, looks  like it works and there is no content in body and hence no height for body.. to test give some height as well

Comment: @NagaSaiA the element selector (body) is not even highlighting to show, i have change what the selector is supposed to do and it wasnt making and changes to the page

Comment: The question should be updated to include  shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please do not post images of code.

Answer (score 2):

Can't see any issues except of your code editor doesn't highlight the syntax.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Personal Size</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width:600px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color: #ff9500;
            padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
            border: 5px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i used your code and the body tag wont even get highlighted to show that its working

Answer (score 1):

Works in jsbin, just try it in jsbin bro
[image: the image]